# Salesforce upload large files upto 250GB through visualforce to external server

Tags: upload, salesforce, visualforce

Hello All I want to upload files to my external system using SOAP APIs. My requirements -

1. upload large files to third party system using SOAP API.
2. File size can be of 250GB.

Limitation that can restrict me -

1. maximum file size that can be uploaded - 5MB
2. maximum Heap size - 6MB. even if i want to upload usign  SOAP API i will still need to hold blob value in controller.
3. maximum web service reqquest limit - one of the main issues that i feel is 3MB limit on webservice call out, in this case i can not send SOAP request of more than 3MB.

Please help me out on this tricky solution. let me know if any further details required.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Can you ask this question on salesforce.stackexchange.com? Community is dedicated to salesforce.

Comment: Did you find the right approach?